# Pull data doesn't show "0" but missing (blank space)

Tags: looker-studio

When I try to pull data from Facebook Ads - for the days that there is no spending, on the Data Studio Dashboard it doesn't show "0" - it is just blank space. Does someone know how to get the Dashboard to display "0"? I need it to run some calculations which I can't right now. It works well on days where we do spend, but not when we don't.

I tried fixing the source from where I pull the data, but to no avail, it still doesn't show "0" but simply - blank space on the days when we didn't spend any money.

Answer (score 0):

you could try [NARY_MAX](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7583429?hl=en)

a calculated field as shown in the screenshot can be used to replace null values with numerical

[image]